# How to create adsense ads using only the users account id?

Tags: adsense

I have a website with articles and I want to share the adsense revenue of the articles with the article writers (in percentage of 90%). I`we created a PHP code that rotates the ads, but I have a problem. I`we discovered that It`s not enough the account ID, i need a the ad slot number, too.

It would be much better if the user should send me only his account id, because else each user would need to create the ad in it`s own adsense account and send me the whole code and than I would need to check if the ad is the size I need.

Any suggestions ? Is it possible to rotate the ads only by the user id ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the old (but well working) AdSense code. It looks like this:

```
<script>
    google_ad_client="YOUR-PUB-ID";
    google_ad_width=300;
    google_ad_height=250;
    google_ad_format="300x250_as";
    google_ad_type="image";
    google_color_border="f3f3f3";
    google_color_bg="f3f3f3";
    google_color_link="313135";
    google_color_text="626262";
    google_color_url="2c89bc";
    google_ui_features="rc:0";
</script>
<script src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js"></script>
```

Available google_ad_type: 
'text_image',
'text',
'image',
for link units: omit this param.

Ad formats are:
728x90_as (Leaderboard),
468x60_as (Banner),
234x60_as (Half Banner),
125x125_as (Button),
120x600_as (Skyscraper),
160x600_as (Wide Skyscraper),
180x150_as (Small Rectangle),
120x240_as (Vertical Banner),
200x200_as (Small Square),
250x250_as (Square),
300x250_as (Rectangle),
336x280_as (Large Rectangle)

Link unit formats:
120x90_0ads_al (4 links),
120x90_0ads_al_s (5 links),
160x90_0ads_al (4 links),
160x90_0ads_al_s (5 links),
180x90_0ads_al (4 links),
180x90_0ads_al_s (5 links),
200x90_0ads_al (4 links),
200x90_0ads_al_s (5 links),
468x15_0ads_al (4 links),
468x15_0ads_al_s (5 links),
728x15_0ads_al (4 links),
728x15_0ads_al_s (5 links)

Just play around. The other values are self explanatory ... Width/height must match the selected ad format's width and height. That's how we do it on Pagewizz.com and Wizzley.com with some ten thousands of users.